# Complex analysis - open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> lemma **10.29**[image]
>
> Theorem **10.30**[image]

I cannot follow the proofs to the following theorems in my textbook, especially the equation (1) in theorem **10.30**. How did it come out from the Lemma? why is it $\frac{1}{2}$? Is there a step-by-step way to prove them so that I might understand?

Suppose $f$ is analytic on $D$, $z_0 \in D$, and $f'(z_0)\neq 0$. Then $D$ contains a neighborhood $D'$ such that

1. $f$ is one-to-one in $D'$,
2. the mapping of $D'$ is an open
   set, and
3. $f$ has a analytic inverse on $D'$.

Comment: Can you please post the lemma also?

Comment: Hi, I just edited it. Both the lemma and theorem should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Since we know $g(z_0,z_0)=f'(z_0)$ in Lemma 10.29 has modulus $\lvert f'(z_0)\rvert\neq 0$ and $g$ is continuous, there is a neighbourhood $U_1\times U_2$ of $(z_0,z_0)$ in $\Omega\times\Omega$ such that $\lvert g\rvert>\frac12\lvert f'(z_0)\rvert$.  The $\frac12$ is just a reasonable constant chosen in $(0,1)$.  Then $V=U_1\cap U_2$ has $V\times V\subseteq U_1\times U_2$ and by definition of $g$ we have $f=\varphi$ is injective on $V$.

Comment: Sorry, how |g|>(1/2)|f′(z0)| follows from continuity and nonzero f'(z_0)?

Comment: Select the open neighbourhood $\{\zeta\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert\zeta\rvert>\frac12\lvert f'(z_0)\rvert\}$ of $f'(z_0)$.  Taking inverse image $g^{-1}$, and apply definition of continuity.